# How to determine $f(0)$?

Tags: functions

$$f(ax+b) = x$$
$$f(a) = \dfrac{b}{a}$$

I want to determine $f(0)$ from given equations.

**My attempt:**

$$f(a)=  \dfrac{b}{a} \implies f(0) = \dfrac{b}{0} = \text{undefined} $$

However, directly determining $f(0)$ makes no sense in this case. Could you assist me with that?

Comment: Substitute $x=\dfrac{-b}{a}$.

Comment: Surely $a$ is a constant here and not a variable?

Comment: @Enzo Not possible to find a numberical value from the facts given. Also, if $a$ is a constant then using $a=0$ is wrong. You must determine $f(0)$ from the initial expression.

Comment: @Rebellos Assume that $a, b \neq 0 \in \mathcal{R}$, Is it the same in this case?

Comment: @Enzo Yes. Also if you want to typeset the set of real numbers, try \mathbb R which produces $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Rebellos but I still dont think $a$ and $b$ are constants since the question wants me to evaluate numerical value.

Comment: "Determine $f(0)$" does not mean "find a numerical value". Also, if $a,b \in \mathbb R$ are constants, then the expression yielded will be a number, just expressed in an arbitrary way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the way upon computing, the function is $f(x)=\dfrac{b(2x-a)}{a^2}$ and $f(0)=\dfrac{-b}{a}$. Further using $f(ax+b)=x$ we get $b=\dfrac{a}{2}$. So the function is $f(x)=\dfrac{2x-a}{2a}$ and $f(0)=\dfrac{-1}{2}$, $f(a)=\dfrac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you want the argument of your given function to be equal to zero. Thus, considering the argument of the funtion $f(ax+b) = x$, we have :

$$ax + b = 0 \Leftrightarrow x = -\frac{b}{a}$$

Then, $f(0)$ would be yielded for $x= -b/a$, thus again by substituting in the first function expression :

$$f(0)=-\frac{b}{a}=-f(a)$$

Comment: But is it possible to find a numerical value?

Comment: @Enzo No, since all your given expressions involve arbitrary constants.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a start - and contrary to comments, there is a solution.

Let $y=ax+b$ so that $f(y)=x=\cfrac {y-b}a$ so now we have expressed $f$ as a linear function of its argument.

I have not yet used the value for $f(a)$ that has been given, so this is the next step.